# Ошибка при переходе на новую страницу :HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing

Tags: java, html, http, servlet

Имеется сервлет, который должен отправить `HTML`-страницу по запросу `/createapp`, но выбрасывает ошибку:

```
Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

В `web.xml` прописан этот сервлет, в `HTML`-файле есть форма `action="/createapp" method="POST">`. Но происходит переполнение стека, я понять и не имею почему.

```
 public class CreateAppServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private final AccountService accountService;
    public CreateAppServlet(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
                       HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/createapp");
     

        view.forward(req, resp);


    }
}
```

Comment: Так у Вас же рекурсия получается, есть сервлет `/createapp` и внутри этого же сервлета пытаетесь перейти на `/createapp`. Не очень понятно, зачем в doGet вызывать doPost, по идее doGet должен вернуть хтмл страницу без вызова `view.forward(req, resp);`

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш совет, теперь рекурсии не происходит.  Но я не совсем понимаю как можно реализовать  отображение хтмл страницы в таком случае. Я ведь могу указать вместо URL просто ссылку на сам файл, чтобы сервлет отображал его?                                      
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/apps.html");

    }